# ansible-playbook could not be found when executing through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am trying to run an ansible-playbook through jenkins but i am ending up with an error that says

```
"ERROR! the playbook: /home/ansible/apache/provision.yml could not be found"
```

I have tried to execute the playbook manually and it works just fine. I tried to debug in permissions perspective. Ansible playbook is owned by user "ansible" and group "ansible". Jenkins is run by user "jenkins" and it is part of "ansible" group as well, but nothing works. Below is the what's getting printed in console output. Can you guys advise how i can troubleshoot this ?

```
*
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Apache-Provision


[Apache-Provision] $ /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /home/ansible/apache/provision.yml -s -U ansible -f 5

ERROR! the playbook: /home/ansible/apache/provision.yml could not be found

FATAL: command execution failed
hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:262)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:232)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Ansible playbook execution failed
Finished: FAILURE*
```

Comment: Being in the group does not mean the group has read permission on the file, or read and execute permission on the parent directories.  It is quite possible that `/home/ansible` does not have group read and execute permissions.

Comment: yes, you are right, my jenkins master is using user to connect to my jenkins slave on another user, when I put the playbook under my /root directory, the general user does not have permission to find this playbook. thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might have renamed your Jenkins job from the console and whenever you rename it a new workspace with updated name is been created please check with it and update the workspace path in jenkins configuration.